# Drools 6.5 Pseudo Clock

Tags: drools, drools-fusion

I have some difficulties to do Drools run in pseudo clock.
I configure my engine in stream Mode, and choose the kind of clock I use thru realMode property.

```
    Date refDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    boolean realMode = false;
    SessionPseudoClock clock = null;

    KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();

    KieSessionConfiguration config = KieServices.Factory.get().newKieSessionConfiguration();
    if(realMode) {
        config.setOption( ClockTypeOption.get("realtime") );                        
    } else {
        config.setOption( ClockTypeOption.get("pseudo") );  
    }

    KieContainer kc = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
    KieSession ksession = kc.newKieSession("cep-rules",config);
    KieRuntimeLogger logger = ks.getLoggers().newFileLogger( ksession, "./out/helloworld" );

    addNewLogLine (ksession, "GDE" , 0);
    addNewLogLine (ksession, "GDE" , 11);
    addNewLogLine (ksession, "GDE" , 3);
    addNewLogLine (ksession, "GDE" , 8);

    logger.close();

    ksession.dispose();
```

The code of AddNewLogLine Function

```
    if( realMode) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delaiInSeconds*1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    } else {
        if (clock==null) {
            clock = ksession.getSessionClock();
        }
        clock.advanceTime( delaiInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
    }
    delai += delaiInSeconds;

    LogItem logLine = new LogItem();
    logLine.setEventDate(new Date (refDate.getTime()+(delai*1000)));
    logLine.setMessage("Message number " + count);
    logLine.setSourceSystemName(sourceSystemName);

    System.out.println(logLine);
    ksession.insert( logLine );

    ksession.fireAllRules();
```

I leave appart some extra code that is not relevant for my problema.

The rule :

```
    declare LogItem
        @role (event)
        @timestamp( eventDate )
    end

    rule "LogInserted"
        dialect "mvel"
        when
            l : LogItem ( )
        then
        System.out.println ("New Log inside from " + l.getSourceSystemName() );
    end

    rule "Nb Log SameSystem" 
        dialect "mvel"
        when
            accumulate( LogItem ( sourceSystemName == "GDE") over window:time(10s) ; $cnt: count(1); $cnt == 2 )
        then
        System.out.println ("2 Logs in engine" );
    end
```

The objective : Detect two logs line in a window of 10 seconds.
The first and seconds are not (11s) and the 2 following lines, yes.

In real mode it works fine. Here is the result :

```
    LogItem { message : Message number 1, date : 28/03/2017 11:17:26, sourceSystemName : GDE }
    New Log inside from GDE
    LogItem { message : Message number 2, date : 28/03/2017 11:17:37, sourceSystemName : GDE }
    New Log inside from GDE
    LogItem { message : Message number 3, date : 28/03/2017 11:17:40, sourceSystemName : GDE }
    New Log inside from GDE
    2 Logs in engine
    LogItem { message : Message number 4, date : 28/03/2017 11:17:48, sourceSystemName : GDE }
    New Log inside from GDE
    2 Logs in engine
```

In pseudo clock mode it **doesn't** work. Because the 4 lines are inserted in the same time, so the 2 first activate the rule. So the Pseudo clock isn't used.

Here is the result :

```
    LogItem { message : Message number 1, date : 28/03/2017 11:17:26, sourceSystemName : GDE }
    New Log inside from GDE
    LogItem { message : Message number 2, date : 28/03/2017 11:17:37, sourceSystemName : GDE }
    New Log inside from GDE
    2 Logs in engine
    LogItem { message : Message number 3, date : 28/03/2017 11:17:40, sourceSystemName : GDE }
    New Log inside from GDE
    LogItem { message : Message number 4, date : 28/03/2017 11:17:48, sourceSystemName : GDE }
    New Log inside from GDE
```

I suppose it's because I don't manage de pseudo clock. But I'm not able to find where I'm wrong.

Anybody ?
Thanks in advance;

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is due to incorrect manipulation of the pseudo-clock. Also, for best results, run the session in a thread of its own which executes fireUntilHalt:

```
Runnable fireUntilHaltRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //      System.out.println( "fireUntilHalt" );
        kSession.fireUntilHalt()
    }
};
Thread fireUntilHaltThread = new Thread(fireUntilHaltRunnable);
```

Facts are inserted from another thread. If you are running tests with the pseudo-clock, make sure the pseudo-clock is set to the timestamp of the event if you are using events that contain the timestamp as a field:

```
private void advance( Date eventDate ){
    long currentTime = clock.getCurrentTime();
    long eventTime = eventDate.getTime();
    clock.advanceTime( eventTime - currentTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
}
```

Do this *before* you insert the next fact. There is no need to sleep between inserts.